# Circuits Reduction

Tags: circuit-analysis

Im new to electrical circuits and Im trying to understand when resistances are in series and in paralel.

Im studying this diagram

[image]

Im I able to join R4 and R5 in series? Is the same idea applicable to R2 and R5? Im doubting about this because both R4 and R2 are connected to R so maybe that might not allow me to apply add the resistances. Can anyone validate my ideas and explain to me this circuit more precisely?

Thanks

Comment: Why does R4 and R2 being connected to R mean you can't combine them in series with R5? You can. R is irrelevant. Imagine compressing the wires together until R4 and R5 and R2 are right next to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R2, R4 and R5 are in series, and that group is in parallel with R.  If you re-draw it like so, it may be clearer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzyMk3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Paint the nodes (either in your mind or on paper)

[image]

Any components that have the same color on each end are in parallel. So, from the above coloring we can see that R2 and R5 have three different colors on their four ends, so they are in series, combine them. And then repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

Definition: 2 terminal components are in series if an end from one connects to an end of the other, with nothing else connected at that point.  They're in parallel if they connect at both ends. You can work out the values of voltage, current and resistance with successive applications of ohm's law. For example, in your figure, R2 and R5 are in series, so the current through them is the same. The voltage across the combination is I*R3 + I*R5, so the voltage across them is equal to I*(R2+R3), and the equivalent  resistance is their sum. As a second example, for parallel connections, R2+R5+R4 (their series equivalent) is 6.6 ohms.  That resistance is in parallel with R.  If Vp  is the voltage across both R and the 6.6 ohms combination, the sum of the currents through the two branches will be Vp/R + Vp/6.6. The equivalent resistance, after some algebra, will be 6.6*R/(6.6+R). Series and parallel are not the only two connections to learn about but they suffice for your question.